# how to sort number to desired in c#?

Tags: c#, sorting

for each element that their difference with former is less than three, order them in descending

```
numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,13,18,25,30,31,32,33}

desired = {6,5,4,3,2,1,13,18,25,33,32,31,30}
```

for example in numbers list ,Because difference between 6 and 5  is less than 3 sort them in descending

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: How would that work?  If you start with 123456 as elements ABCDEF and apply the rule Previous - Current < 3 then you skip A(1) and look at B(2).  B-1<3 so you switch them.  Now you have 213456.  Start again at A, skip A, look at B, skip B, look at C.  C-B<3 so you swap B & C and get 231456.  Proceeding in that vein you then go to 321456 AND THEN when you compare C to D (1 and 4) you are now AT 3, which means you don't swap them, so you'll end up with 321654 and be done with that sequence.

Comment: I am confused. Why is the end of the desired set "30, 33, 32, 31" and not "33, 32, 31, 30" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 13, 18, 25, 30, 31, 32, 33 };

var result = numbers.GroupAdjacent((x, y) => y - x < 3)
                    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x))
                    .ToArray();

// result == { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 13, 18, 25, 33, 32, 31, 30 }
```

with

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacent<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> adjacent)
{
    var g = new List<T>();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        if (g.Count != 0 && !adjacent(g.Last(), x))
        {
            yield return g;
            g = new List<T>();
        }
        g.Add(x);
    }
    yield return g;
}
```

Comment: Just tried that and got - "6,5,4,3,2,1,13,18,25,33,32,31,30", it differs from "6,5,4,3,2,1,13,18,25,30,33,32,31". "25,33" - here is should be switch to ASC. But anyway looks like with minor tweak it would work using such extension method, I impressed

Comment: @sllev: The difference between 30 and 31 is less then three, no?

Comment: looks like author of the question was wrong when provides the expected result set

Answer (score 3):

hello that is too complex.. 

As i dont have the Visual studio so i wrote the code in `javascript` that will cover your requirement

```
     <script>
        var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,13,18,25,30,31,32,33];

        alert(custom_sort(a));

        function custom_sort(a) {
            var objArrayList = {};              
            var index = 0;
            var where_i_am = 0;
            objArrayList[index] = Array();
            if(a[1]-a[0] < 3){
                where_i_am = 1;
                objArrayList[index].push(a[0]);
            } else {
                where_i_am = 2;
                objArrayList[index].push(a[0]);
            }
            for(var i=1;i<a.length;i++) {
                if(a[i]-a[i-1] < 3) {
                    if(where_i_am ==2) {
                        where_i_am = 1;
                        index++;
                        objArrayList[index] = Array();
                    }
                    if(where_i_am==1) 
                        objArrayList[index].push(a[i]);
                } else {
                    if(where_i_am==1) {
                        where_i_am =2;
                        index++;
                        objArrayList[index] = Array();
                    }
                    if(where_i_am==2)  {
                        objArrayList[index].push(a[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            var new_array = new Array();
            for(var obj in objArrayList) {
                var array_val = objArrayList[obj];
                if(array_val[1] - array_val[0] < 3) {
                    new_array = new_array.concat(sort_desc(array_val));
                } else {
                    new_array = new_array.concat(sort_asc(array_val));
                }
            }
            return new_array;


        }
        function sort_asc(array_val){
            for(var i =0;i<array_val.length;i++) {
                for(var j=0;j<array_val.length;j++) {
                    if(array_val[i] < array_val[j]) {
                        var temp = array_val[i];
                        array_val[i] = array_val[j];
                        array_val[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return array_val;
        }
        function sort_desc(array_val){
            for(var i =0;i<array_val.length;i++) {
                for(var j=0;j<array_val.length;j++) {
                    if(array_val[i] > array_val[j]) {
                        var temp = array_val[i];
                        array_val[i] = array_val[j];
                        array_val[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return array_val;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: If anyone can test it then I would upvode no matter that this is not a C# and looks not perfect...

Comment: @sllev Presumably you have a browser :P

Answer (score 2):

For me such algorithm looks very non standard so I feel there are few algorithms should be used to achieve good results in terms of complexity. There is one very important question - **does an initial array already sorted?**

Any way you can start by splitting array by sub arrays:

1. Split such array to multiple (with some indicator whether each one should be sorted 
   ASC or DESC)

Then if an initial array is not sorted:

1. Then sort all of sub arrays one by one using QuickSort, so you will get a set of sorted arrays
2. Then you can sort sub arrays using the first element of each so order of sub arrays should be saved (Hope I described it clear enough)

But if an initial array was sorted:

1. Merge sub arrays in initially preserved order

Comment: @sllev,yes first sorted in ascending

Comment: @christopherCurrens,no,for test your knowledge.

Comment: @puria : yes I can, but will not do it because much better give you a chance to pupm up your skills

Comment: @puria Why don't you test your knowledge?